# Selecting the old price from an audit table for each User ID

Tags: sql

This join works for what I'm trying to do but is very slow and seems a very inefficient option.

Basically the inner most query tells me when the `appeal_audit.price` has changed, the outer one shows me only values where it changes, and the outer most one only gives me the earliest one to stop duplication when it changed multiple times.

```
left join(
select * from (
Select
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserId order by auditdate) as RowNo,
userid,
OldPrice,
auditdate
from (
select
UserId,
Price,
lag(appeal_audit.price) over (partition by appeal_audit.userid order by appeal_audit.auditdate) as OldPrice,
case when appeal_audit.Price <> lag(appeal_audit.price) over (partition by appeal_Audit.userid order by appeal_audit.auditdate) then 1 else 0 end as Flag,
AuditDate
from Appeal_Audit) t4
where t4.flag = 1) t5
where t5.RowNo = 1 ) t6
on t6.userid = userdetails.userid
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]. (I.e. simplify. Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: BTW, left justified SQL is so hard to read (and to write...)

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag would all help.